# Overlapping Sections with Bulma CSS

Tags: css, bulma

I am trying to learn Bulma and I want to show a simple page with this layout:

```
<header>
<hero>
<section>
<footer>
```

I don't understand why they overlap with each other instead of being clearly one below the other.

There is a dummy container that is obviously misplaced and hidden by the header.
The overlapping is also obvious by the search bar that is both over part of the footer and the hero.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bLgOWb

```
<nav class="navbar is-primary is-fixed-top has-text-white">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <img id="logo" alt="DUB Logo" src="http://code.dlang.org/images/dub-header.png"/>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-menu">
            <div class="navbar-start">
                <div id="navItem" class="navbar-item">Primo</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<section class="section">
    <div class="container dummy">
    </div>
</section>
<div class="hero ">
    <div class="container has-text-centered is-size-1">
        <h1 class="title"> Explore and use libraries and software</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="search" class="container">
    <div class="columns searchBlock ">
        <div class="column is-paddingless">
            <form>
                <input class="input searchInput" type="text" placeholder="Search">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class='column is-3 is-paddingless'>

        </div>
        <div class='column is-2 is-paddingless'>
            <a class='button is-primary  searchButton'>Search</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container is-text-centered">
        <p> Footer </p>
    </div>
</footer>
<script src="old.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`.hero-body` is missing

```
<div class="hero">
  <div class="hero-body">
    <div class="container has-text-centered">
      <h1 class="title"> Explore and use libraries and software </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Bulma - Hero](https://bulma.io/documentation/layout/hero/)

Answer (score -2):

I think problem with **column** . change column margin follow this

```
.columns {
     marign:0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any change with your proposed modification